# How to install amazon auto scale feature in Windows machines?

Tags: windows, windows-7

When I am trying to install auto scale feature on my system, it's showing many errors. When I run the command

```
dir "%AWS_AUTOSCALE_HOME/bin%"
```

it's showing an error that the system cannot find the path specified. After setting the path it's showing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch, but it wouldn't be

```
dir "%AWS_AUTOSCALE_HOME%/bin"
```

would it?